# Error connect to postgres(pg_close)

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have this following code:

```
  require 'dataload.php';
  function get_objects($where,$name=false) {

    global $epsg, $cnt_array;

    $db = Dataload::getDB();

    $columns="osm_id, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way,4326)) as way2, name, ward, \"healthcare:speciality\", information, description, social_facility, \"social_facility:for\", capacity, operator, official_name, official_status, phone, website, \"addr:full\", \"addr:city\", \"addr:district\", \"addr:postcode\", opening_hours, \"addr:hamlet\", \"addr:street\", fax, email, allhuman, adulthuman, childhuman, \"healthcare:heart\", \"healthcare:mind\", \"healthcare:maternity_light\", \"healthcare:maternity_hard\", \"healthcare:dtp\", \"ward:speciality_gynaecology\", \"ward:speciality_maternity\", \"ward:speciality_infectious_diseases\", \"ward:speciality_neurology\", \"ward:speciality_paediatrics\", \"ward:speciality_general\", \"ward:speciality_surgery\", \"internet_access:operator\", \"internet_access:speed\", \"wifi_access:ssid\"";
    $query="select ".$columns." from test_point where ".$where;

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    $geojson = array(
                     'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
                     'features'  => array(),
                     'crs' => array(
                                    'type' => 'EPSG',
                                    'properties' => array('code' => '4326')
                     )
    );
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $gos18_work = array();
    if($name=="gos18") {
        $query_gos18_work = "select * from gos18_work where obj=".$myrow["osm_id"];
        $result_gos18_work = pg_query($query_gos18_work);
        if (!$result_gos18_work) {
            echo "Problem with query " . $query_gos18_work . "<br/>";
            echo pg_last_error();
            exit();
        }
        while($myrow_gos18 = pg_fetch_assoc($result_gos18_work)) {
            $gos18_work[] = array(
                blah=>blah
            );
        }
    }

          $feature = array(
                           'type' => 'Feature',
                           'id' => $myrow["osm_id"],
                           'layer' => $epsg,
                           'geometry' => json_decode($myrow["way2"], true),
                           'geometry_name' => 'way',
                           'properties' => array(
                                                 'name' => $myrow["name"],
                      )
          );
          // Add feature array to feature collection array
          array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

    }

    // Close database connection
    pg_close($db);

 }
 if(blah) ......get_objects($where);....
```

Dataload(class where get DB):

```
   public static function getDB() {
    return pg_connect('host=notlocalhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=dbname') 
        or die("not connect".pg_last_error());
}
```

This working if DB connect to localhost, but another server(copy site without DB) return error:

> Warning: pg_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in my.php on line....

BUT! If comment `pg_close()` this working without any errors and return result from DB.

Comment: Why do you use explicit connection parameter in pg_close and not use it in pg_query? I guess something is wrong with your $db variable.

Comment: Yes, without $db variable working. If use $db in pg_query i have error too. But with localhost working without error... Не понятно в чем причина ошибки одного и того же скрипта в разных серверах его работы, но php по разному воспринимает скрипт, может версии php. Например если функции get_object не задать значение по-умолчанию второго параметра то она не будет работать на удаленном сервере, но будет работать на локальном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from php manual for pg_connect:

> Beware about writing something like
>
> ```
> <?php
> function getdb_FAILS() {
>     return pg_connect("...") or die('connection failed');
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> It will return a boolean.  This will appear to be fine if you don't
>   use the return value as a db connection handle, but will fail if you
>   do.
>
> Instead, use:
>
> ```
> <?php
> function getdb() {
>     $db = pg_connect("...") or die('connection failed');
>     return $db;
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> which actually returns a handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My fault, dont see.